# "latency to do" or "latency to doing"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, gerund-vs-infinitive, verb-patterns

What's correct?

> Environmental enrichment leads to more active behaviour in an open field and causes a shorter **latency to interact** with a novel object"

Or should it be 'latency to interacting'?

The sentence is about battery chickens. The idea is that a richer environment causes chickens to be bolder when encountering a new object; they take less time before they approach it

Comment: I'd say *latency **in** interacting*. Or *latency **when** interacting*. Or maybe *latency **for** interacting*. But to me, it feels like the preposition *to* is just wrong here.

Comment: @PeterShor yes, or "for interacting" BTW do you understand the sentence? is it just me?

Comment: The original sentence is about battery chickens. The idea is that a richer environment causes chickens to be bolder when encountering a new object; they take less time before they approach it etc.

Comment: What do you think of 'latency before interacting'?

Comment: Beth if you want to notify a user you must add @ before their username. @PeterShor will now receive a message in his inbox. P.S I think your solution works very well. You can post an answer and that way users can give you feedback.

Comment: Please, Beth, what do you want to use *latency* to mean here?

The the rest of the sentence makes no difference, even though it’s far from just Mari-Lou and I for two don’t understand it at all.

Only *latency to interact* matters, and I think Peter was being diplomatic. I’d say *latency in interaction* or *latency when interacting* but the preposition *to* has no place here.

Comment: Robbie, it's not my sentence, but in a student's piece I was correcting. I suspect that there is a tendency to latch onto terms like 'latency' and mis-
 or overuse them when simpler words would do. How would you rewrite the sentence?